# Correlation between two successive rows in the same dataframe in the same column_python

Tags: correlation

I have a large dataframe with 36 columns, I want to calculate correlation between two successive rows.
I tried

data.corrwith(data, axis=0, method='pearson', drop=False)

wrong result:

('Amplitude', 0)     1.0
('Amplitude', 1)     1.0
('Amplitude', 2)     1.0
('Amplitude', 3)     1.0
('Amplitude', 4)     1.0
('Amplitude', 5)     1.0
('Amplitude', 6)     1.0
('Amplitude', 7)     1.0
('Amplitude', 8)     1.0
('Amplitude', 9)     1.0
('Amplitude', 10)    1.0
('Amplitude', 11)    1.0
('Amplitude', 12)    1.0
....

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eHwci.png)

This is a capture of dataset.

Thank you,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [df.corr](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.corr.html) this will return a data frame with all pairs of columns and the correlation between them. Here is the code:

```
df.set_index('Time', drop=True).T.corr()
```

Comment: df.corr for correlation between columns but I want correlation between rows (observations)

Comment: You can transpose you transpose the dataframe and then use df.corr https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transpose.html

Comment: Can you provide a glimpse of your data? It is kind of hard to help without seeing the data format

Comment: I edited the answer, see if is that what you want. I guess the problem was the time column @GhitaLayile